Apache 2.4 shows default SSL certificate instead of requested domain
I am running 5 domains on my Apache server using Vhosts.  The first domain on the httpd-vhosts.conf and httpd-ssl.conf work fine.  If I go to one of the other domains, it will try to use the default SSL certificate.  If I refresh the page, it will use the correct certificate.
httpd-vhosts.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin     webmaster@patricklewis.net
    DocumentRoot    "/Library/WebServer/Sites/"
    ServerName      localhost
    ErrorLog        "/private/var/log/apache2/local-error_log"
    CustomLog       "/private/var/log/apache2/local-access_log" common
    ErrorDocument   404 "/index.html"
    <Location />
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0 ::1
        Allow from localhost
        Allow from 192.168
        Allow from 10
        Satisfy Any
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      britishcarinteriors.com
    ServerAlias     www.britishcarinteriors.com
    ServerAdmin     webmaster@patricklewis.net
    DocumentRoot    "/Library/WebServer/Sites/britishcar/site/"
    ErrorLog        "/private/var/log/apache2/britishcar-error_log"
    CustomLog       "/private/var/log/apache2/britishcar-access_log" common
    ErrorDocument   404 "/404.php"
    Redirect        permanent / https://www.britishcarinteriors.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      brandonmgclub.com
    ServerAlias     www.brandonmgclub.com
    ServerAdmin     webmaster@brandonmgclub.com
    DocumentRoot    "/Library/WebServer/Sites/BrandonMGclub/site/"
    ErrorLog        "/private/var/log/apache2/brandonmgclub-error_log"
    CustomLog       "/private/var/log/apache2/brandonmgclub-access_log" common
    Redirect        permanent / https://www.brandonmgclub.com/
</VirtualHost>



httpd-ssl.conf
      
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine               on
    ServerName              www.britishcarinteriors.com
    ServerAlias             britishcarinteriors.com
    ServerAdmin             patrick@patricklewis.net
    DocumentRoot            "/Library/WebServer/Sites/britishcar/site"
    ErrorDocument           404 "/404.php"
    ErrorLog                "/private/var/log/apache2/britishcarinteriors-SSLerror_log"
    TransferLog             "/private/var/log/apache2/britishcarinteriors-SSLaccess_log"
    SSLCertificateFile      "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/britishcarinteriors_com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/britishcarinteriors_com.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile    "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/britishcarinteriors_com.ca-bundle"
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
#       downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    
    CustomLog   "/private/var/log/apache2/ssl_request_log" \
        "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
                        

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine               on
    ServerName              www.brandonmgclub.com
    ServerAlias             brandonmgclub.com
    ServerAdmin             webmaster@brandonmgclub.com
    DocumentRoot            "/Library/WebServer/Sites/BrandonMGclub/site"
    ErrorDocument           404 "/404error.php"
    ErrorLog                "/private/var/log/apache2/brandonmgclub.com-SSLerror_log"
    TransferLog             "/private/var/log/apache2/brandonmgclub.com-SSLaccess_log"
    SSLCertificateFile      "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/brandonmgclub.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/brandonmgclub.com.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile    "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/brandonmgclub.com.ca-bundle"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
#       downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    
    CustomLog   "/private/var/log/apache2/ssl_request_log" \
        "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>

I don't get the error at home on my Apple computers, but can get it on my PC for work.
Here is the error from Chrome on PC:
Wrong Domain Certificate
